# What AngularJS data do you have to place a $watch() on?

Tags: angularjs

I've been working on an application using AngularJS and I've been learning the ins and outs of asynchronous data loading. I noticed that sometimes I need to place a watch on my data, so that my controllers/directives wait until the data is retrieved before continuing.

My question is: at what times do I need to place a watch? Up until now, I've only placed one if I noticed my application won't run without it, but I don't fully understand the logic behind it. Is it only needed when I am retrieving data from an external source using http? Or could it be that I need a watch() statement even if I'm getting data already stored in local variables?

Thanks!

Comment: I've developed many pages with angular, and I've almost never had to use a watch. You should post an example which doesn't work without a watch, explain how is doesn't work, and maybe we can tell you why a watch is needed, or how to better solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A special feature of Angular.JS is it's ability to manage 2 way bindings between JavaScript variables and the DOM.  In order to do this, it automatically registers watchers on any variable referenced inside an expression (`{{ }}`).  A loop called $digest is run when it detects changes to a watchExpression to process all the watchers on the current scope and it's children.

Manually registering a $watch is normally not necessary, but can be used in situations where you need the $digest to update changes to an expression which is in a different $scope, or if you are interested in reacting to a change for which you have not already established an automatic binding.  The most common usage for $watch would be in a directive, to update the DOM when a $scope value changes.  If you are using $watch in a controller, you are probably doing something wrong.

Some Guidelines For Use:

- DO use $watch in directives to update the DOM when a $scope value changes.
- DON'T use $watch in a controller. It's hard to test and completely unnecessary in almost every case. Use a method on the scope to update the value(s) the watch was changing instead.